# Dramatiq worker getting killed every often

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, python-3.6, dramatiq

I have started a dramatiq worker to do some task and after a point, it is just stuck and throws this below-mentioned error after some time.

**[MainThread] [dramatiq.MainProcess] [CRITICAL] Worker with PID 53 exited unexpectedly (code -9). Shutting down...**

What can be the potential reason for this to occur? Are System resources a constraint?

This queuing task is run inside a Kubernetes pod

Comment: Any update on it? I have the same issue.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, although the CRITICAL message occurs after the termination process beings and the code is -11. There is something sending a SIGTERM signal to a worker. Did you find the reason for your case?

Comment: Same issue with me, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check kernel logs (/var/log/kern.log and /var/log/kern.log.1)
The Worker might be getting killed due to OOMKiller (OutOfMemory).
To resolve this try to increase the memory if you are running in a docker or pod.